# Favicon does not show on Webkit browsers

Tags: safari, google-chrome, favicon

I'm having problems with putting a favicon on my website.

I have this code

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/ico" href="img/favicon.ico">
```

And for some reason Firefox shows the favicon fine, but on Webkit browsers its not showing up. I tried Google Chrome and Safari on a Mac and its not showing up; do I need to do something for these browsers?

Comment: What if you put the icon to root dir instead of img? Does it work then?

Comment: good Idea, lemme give that a try

Comment: sorry was having svn issues with moving favicon, but you were correct Frantisek thank you, please answer this and ill mark it correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try placing a relative path and change the type to "image/x-icon":

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/img/favicon.ico" />
```

Or just place it on the root:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
```

Comment: I think you should also add the domain to the address, like: "h t t p ://somedomain.com/favicon.ico"