# Adding Favicon to a Website

Tags: html, web, favicon

So i'm trying to add a favicon to my website but everytime I open the site the favicon doesn't show. So in my main template file I have this:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="images/favicon.ico"  />
```

But my site looks like this:
[image]

I've tried refreshing the cache and going into incognito but nothing seems to work...any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried `rel="favicon"`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11221292/local-file-website-favicon-works-in-firefox-not-in-chrome-or-safari-why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=51270. It seems like using `file://` with a favicon won't work in Chrome. Star the issue if you want to see it fixed!

Answer (score 0):

First kudos for doing something most revs overlook. I wrote a blog post with some resources on favicons a few months ago.

[web perf tip add a favicon](http://professionalaspnet.com/archive/2012/04/30/Web-Performance-Tip_3A00_-Make-Sure-You-Have-a-FavIcon.aspx)