# Favicon.ico doesn't appear in title bar

Tags: html, favicon

I am trying to add a favicon.ico in my title but it is not working. The image and the HTML file are in the same folder but it still can't show me the favicon icon.

`<title><link href="\Users\fjoni_000\Desktop\Stuff\Projects\Programming\favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon">Best Of Internet | Front page</title>`

This is the code that I am using. I tried with the Google logo and still it didn't show. This is the code from Google source code:

```
<link href="/images/branding/product/ico/googleg_lodp.ico" rel="shortcut icon">
```

If there is any question similar to mine and has the answer that I'm looking for then please comment it. Also the website is locally hosted NOT online

Comment: <link rel="shortcut icon" href="fav.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>

Comment: @IvanBarayev didn't work

Comment: ok close your browser and open t again. Go to settings of browser and clear all of the history with cache. and open your site again

Comment: still nothing is showing up

Comment: Look att the @freefaller answer. It will work absolutely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<link>` should **not** be within the `<title>`... it should be outside of the `<title>` but still within the `<head>`...

```
<head>
  <title>Best Of Internet | Front page</title>
  <link href="\Users\fjoni_000\Desktop\Stuff\Projects\Programming\favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon">
  ...
```

Although I think the main issue you have is it looks like a local system path, not a URL as understood by your browser.  And you're also missing the `type` attribute

Without knowing the setup of your website server... I would take a complete guess that you want something like...

```
<link href="/Programming/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
```

---

Just as an additional point, if you're able to... simply placing the `favicon.ico` file in the root of your domain is enough for the majority of browsers to pick up.  Then you don't need the `<link>` at all

Comment: that didn't work either. The website is not published it is on my computer only.

Comment: In that case you need to tell the browser the file is local... try (and I'm not promising anything) changing the `href` attribute to `href="file:///C:\Users\fjoni_000\Desktop\Stuff\Projects\Programming\favicon.ico"`

Comment: You should also make it clear in your question that you're talking about a locally hosted site - 99% of readers will assume it's a site on the internet

Comment: <link rel="shortcut icon" href="file:///C:\Users\fjoni_000\Desktop\Stuff\Projects\Programming\favicon.ico‌​" type="image/x-icon"/> this is the code I'm using at the moment

Comment: I would recommend looking through [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11221292/local-file-website-favicon-works-in-firefox-not-in-chrome-or-safari-why)... it appears to be asking the same thing and has lots of answers to try

Comment: the answer of that question worked I just have to change that path of image to mine. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try to clear your browser cache and try again.
Do you have a live URL?

Answer (score 0):

you adding Favicon inside the title tag which is wrong and make sure the icon exist in path.  try this

```
<title>your title</title>
<link href="/images/branding/product/ico/googleg_lodp.ico" rel="shortcut icon">
```