# The Favicon is not showing on my wordpress website especially on Chrome

Tags: html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have uploaded the favicon on my wordpress website but it is not showing on chrome. http://babygearsmalaysia.com

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: It works for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to add a favicon is without `shortcut`, so instead of

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="YOURPATH/favicon.png">
```

you should use

```
<link rel="icon" href="YOURPATH/favicon.png">
```

Even better would be to leave out the tag and just use an favicon.ico file in your root directory. [Further reading](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/rel-shortcut-icon)

Answer (score 1):

I had this very similar issue many times.Finally, I got the solution.

You need to Force a Favicon Refresh in Your WordPress site.

You can do this by adding this code in your header.php file.

```
<link rel="icon" href="http://www.yoursite.com/favicon.ico?v=2" />
```

**?v=2** will reload/refresh your favicon and it will work on every browser and every page. It worked on mine. :)

For detail guide, check here:

**[https://prabinparajuli.com.np/force-a-favicon-refresh-website/](http://prabinparajuli.com.np/force-a-favicon-refresh-website/)**

Answer (score 0):

1) Clear your cache. http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95582 And test another browser, lets say safari. How did you import the favicon?

2) How you should add it:

Normal favicon:

```
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

PNG/GIF favicon:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/gif" href="favicon.gif" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />
```

in the `<head>` Tag.

3) Another thing could be the problem that **chrome can't display** favicons, **if it's local** (not uploaded to a webserver). Only if the file/icon would be in the downloads directory chrome is allowed to load this data - more information about this can be found here: [local (file://) website favicon works in Firefox, not in Chrome or Safari- why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11221292/local-file-website-favicon-works-in-firefox-not-in-chrome-or-safari-why/30037071#30037071)

4) Try to rename it from `favicon.{whatever}` to `{yourfaviconname}.{whatever}` but I would suggest you to still have the normal favicon. This has solved my issue on IE.

5) Found another solution for this which works great! I simply added my favicon as Base64 Encoded Image directly inside the  tag like this:

```
<link href="data:image/x-icon;base64,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" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" />
```

Used this page here for this: http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp

6) I can really suggest you this page: http://www.favicon-generator.org/ to create all types of favicons you need.

Source : https://stackoverflow.com/a/16375622/1581725

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I resolved it without any plugin by simply going to Appearance -> Customize, then Site Identity and I removed the Favicon showing, then I saved. After it's saved, I then went to the site and cleared the cache using CTRL F5.

Then I went back to the dashboard -> Appearance -> Customize -> Site Identity and re-add the favicon, then I saved. Favicon started showing again after I refreshed.

Comment: Did not work for me, got:  **favicon.ico** _Sorry, this file type is not permitted for security reasons._

Answer (score 0):

This is to be configured [inside](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-add-a-favicon-to-your-wordpress-blog/) the Customizer theme.

Answer (score 0):

This thread is old, but did not provide solution for customizer added icon.

Usual problem is explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54715578/10307953

It looks like chrome does not load icon if there is markup error before it in head. Faulty plugins can cause this.
By default icon is printed before closing head tag.

This helped me (in functions.php in child theme):

```
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'wp_site_icon', 99 );
add_action( 'wp_head', 'wp_site_icon', 0 );
```

This way icons are printed on beginning of head tag.