# wordpress site favicon showing all browsers except google chrome

Tags: html, wordpress, image, cross-browser, favicon

In my wordpress site favicon showing all browsers except google chromei would give direct url link also but not working on chrome i used the code like this

```
<link rel="icon" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/favicon.ico"  type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

Comment: Try without the first '/' in href. It might be the same problem as here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13780402/html-favicon-wont-show-on-google-chrome

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML favicon won't show on google chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13780402/html-favicon-wont-show-on-google-chrome)

Comment: Are you 100% sure it's not related to the site being cached with no favicon? Have you tried in an incognito window?

Comment: thanks Victoria, i clear the cache and tried in an incognito window also, still not coming, but in console it will come, have u pls check  on the site https://cloudnippon.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<link rel="icon" href="YOURPATH/favicon.png">
```

[The Favicon is not showing on my wordpress website especially on Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45305516/the-favicon-is-not-showing-on-my-wordpress-website-especially-on-chrome)