# WordPress Favicon not showing on Google Chrome tab

Tags: wordpress, favicon

Since a few weeks, the favicon of my webzine is no longer displayed, and this on the browser of my work, but also on my personal PC.

I do not think I have changed the configuration. I tried to re-upload it, to no avail.

https://www.yubigeek.com/

In the Google Chrome Developer Console, there is an error on favicon.ico (404) but in the source code of the page, this URL is not called.

There are however two tag link with a rel = "icon" and the URL of the favicon, if I click on the links, the images are there.

Comment: I think you have followed the wrong way. WordPress has built in feature to add favicon. You can add favicon via `Appearance > Customize > Site Identity`. For more info please follow https://nerodev.com/how-to-add-favicon-in-wordpress/

Comment: I've already add favicon from Site Identity... It's the only page where I can add the favicon.

Comment: Upload favicon image at least 512px width and 512px height

Comment: Done, but already the same problem. On back, I have the favicon, not on front.

Comment: Any cache is enabled? If so, clear the cache and check.

Comment: I haven't cache...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is due to a `div` markup which wrongly appears if the `head` section of your pages. Such markup should only be in the `body`.

**More details**

Most browsers accept `body`-only markups in `head`. But Chrome has a particular behavior. When this happens, Chrome considers the `head` section to be closed. Therefore, following `head` markups are actually considered to be in the `body`. And since favicon markups do not work when there are in `body`...

This is why your favicon fails on Chrome but works on Firefox.

**How to fix**

Your first two `div` are around line 153, still in the `head`. As a hint, their ids are `fb-root` and `fb-customerchat`. That should help you spot which plugin is doing this.

Should you disable this plugin, at least for now? Your choice.

You should also report this issue to the plugin developer. You must not be the only one impacted by this issue.

Comment: Great! Does this come from a plugin? Or did you injected this code yourself?

Comment: Then I suggest you to inject this code in the footer. See https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/174192/insert-plugin-content-before-body-end

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! :)

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer. I spent hours on this before I found your answer. Someone had put a tracking pixel in the <head> that used an <img> tag.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to add WordPress Favicon is adding favicon via `Appearance > Customize > Site Identity`. Create favicon image at least by `512 x 512` and follow the path to navigate. Then upload the image in `Site Identity` section. `Save` it and you're done.

Please follow [this](https://nerodev.com/how-to-add-favicon-in-wordpress/) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're using a PNG image, you can try to add attribute `type`.

So your link would be something like : `<link rel="icon" href="yourpath" type="image/png">`

**EDIT :** Plus, put your `.ico` file in the root of you website if it's not already done.

Answer (score 0):

This approach might help if you cannot fix invalid head markup explained by @philippe_b:

```
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'wp_site_icon', 99 );
add_action( 'wp_head', 'wp_site_icon', 0 );
```

Add it to functions.php in your child theme. This way we print site icons on top of head.