# favicon not working for one (token) page in chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, favicon

I have a problem with my favicon in Chrome. It won't show in one page. 
I don't really know why but I guess it's because it works with a token, so if the token is different it takes other stuff from my database. in other words the page is never the same. I also tried some other stuff from stackoverflow but it wouldn't work either. Somehow it will work in Microsoft Edge.

this is what I tried so far (header.php):

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/healtywavezicon.png">
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="/healtywavezicon.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="/healtywavezicon.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="/healtywavezicon.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="/healtywavezicon.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="/healtywavezicon.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="/healtywavezicon.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="/healtywavezicon.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="/healtywavezicon.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="/healtywavezicon.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/healtywavezicon.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="192x192" href="/healtywavezicon.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/healtywavezicon.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="/healtywavezicon.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/healtywavezicon.png">
```

I also tried to put it directly in the index.php:

```
<head>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/healtywavezicon.png">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="/healtywavezicon.png">
</head>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your favicon **does not work on Chrome** but **works on Edge, Firefox and others**, this may be because [your header contains a body-only markup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54707758/wordpress-favicon-not-showing-on-google-chrome-tab/54715578#answer-54715578).

Comment: if i show you my code do you think you can help me out?

Comment: Well, this is not super convenient. Your header must be quite big. You should:
1) Spot your icon markups
2) Look for a div or a p that could appear *before* the icon markups

Note: The W3C Validator spots this kind of issue, you submit your code there.

Comment: thanks mate i know what i did wrong i had a break above the code for my css

Comment: Great! This issue can be so annoying... I'm glad you found the culprit!

Answer (score 0):

If you put that in index.PHP then you should make sure that they're in header tags rather than in  tags. otherwise,check the image urls

Comment: i put it in the same folder because it was easier

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a leading `/` in your href, you are referencing a file that will be in the root folder. In case you have your page in a folder on your computer, not serving it from a local web server, the leading `/` will tell the browser to look in the root folder of your filesystem. So the browser expects the file to be at `C:/favicon.ico` or similar, which is probably not what you've expected.

If you have the `favicon.ico` in the same folder as the web page, you could just remove the leading slash, and the icon should be visible.

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />
```

**Update:**

As a debug option, you could try to add a tag that you know works. I borrowed this snippet from the StackOverflow source. Try replacing your link tag with this and see if you get the SO logo as your favicon.

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico">
```

**Update 2:**

It appears that there is a bug reported on Chromium where the favicon isn't displayed if the file is loaded locally, without being served through a web server.

Comment: im working on a server. so that can't be the problem. i need the `/` in my href otherwise it won't work. i tried your **Update** but it won't work... maybe because the site doens't have like one url because of the token?