# HTML favicon not showing up in safari

Tags: html, safari, favicon

I have this favicon:

```
<link href="data:image/x-icon;base64,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" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" />
```

From this website: https://www.favicon.cc/?action=icon&file_id=955561

Okay, so this favicon doesn't show up on safari, but it shows on chrome. So how do I implement this favicon to be seen on all platforms?

Comment: you should have a look at [Base64 icons favicon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52702892/14972999)

Comment: look it - https://caniuse.com/link-icon-svg